# GLSL Vulkan compute shader to efficiently prune zeros from a shared array to make a compressed array

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, glsl, shader, vulkan

I have a vulkan compute shader with an array shared inside the local group and I want to perform the following transform:
[image: Vulkan Shader Zero removal from array]
Basically, I want to remove/prune all the zeros. Is there a fast or parallel method to do this?
I tried to do this in series as follows

```
            shared int arraySize;
            shared int array[256];
            shared int compressed_array[256];

            /*... prepare array in parallel ... */

            // run in series on 1st worker 
            if(gl_LocalInvocationID.x == 0 && gl_LocalInvocationID.y == 0){
               arraySize= 0; // initilize arraySize
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) { 
                    if(array[i] > 0) // incrementally search for non-zeroes
                    {
                        compressed_array[arraySize] = array[i];
                        arraySize= arraySize + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it seems to take 1-2[ms] with 256 elements of the array on my GPU, is there any faster way to do this? A parallel algorithm would presumably be faster, does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: Note that if you're writing the values to non-local storage after compacting, you shouldn't compact them to local storage at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Yuri Kilochek's answer, I was able to find a solution via parallel [prefix-sums/scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)

Suppose a 'flag' array was added to the data that is 1 if the corresponding array cell is non-zero and 0 otherwise. Then a '*parallel exclusive scan*' on the flag array will yield the index of the compressed_array to which invocations with an active flag should write their respective 'array' contents to (scatter operation).
[image]

In Vulkan this can be implemented efficiently using [subgroups](https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-subgroup-tutorial).

However, each subgroup can typically only perform scans up to 32 (Nvidia) or 64 (AMD) elements long while the local group may be several times larger. To perform scans over the whole local group, a layered approach of scans as [described here](https://cachemiss.xyz/blog/parallel-reduce-and-scan-on-the-GPU) and [coded here](https://github.com/mmaldacker/VulkanSubgroups/blob/master/Scan.comp) is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This problem is called *parallel stream compaction*.

Comment: So... what's the algorithm?

Comment: Thank you! Your comment helped me find how to solve it via exclusive scans. I will write a more detailed explanation for future readers.